# Magento 2 Error 500 when viewing all products in a certain category

Tags: magento2, category, error, http-error-500, view

As soon as I select "limit all", i get a server error.

All other pages are working fine. I increased my memory limit to 4 GB, checked file permissions, etc.

My error log just says Error 500.

My best guess is that it could be some kind of limited resources, cause I am working with configurable products (so for every configurable product there are 30 single products).

**Edit:**
The error is: premature end of script. Turning of the cache works for me, however i still need to figure out how to solve it with cache turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Run the follwing commands in the terminal:-

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And Second Solution :-

You developer mode enable and file automatically generated requested and not found. So showing this problem

When facing a 500 error the first thing you should do is search for your webserver error log.

When running on apache it can mostly be found in one of these 2 locations:

```
/var/log/httpd/ -> centos, archlinux

/var/log/apache2/ -> debian, ubuntu
```

And No solve the your problem So Please refer this links :-

**https://magehit.com/blog/solving-500-internal-server-error-in-magento-2/**

Hope help you

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, figured it out so far. I had to overwrite /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/ProductIdentitiesExtender.php

Couldnt figure out what the right path would be to overwrite it. Do you know?
app/code...?

Comment: create the module and overwrite you core files Mymodule/Overwrite/